# Accessing a numeric key in jinja2

Tags: python, jinja2

This code doesn't work:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from jinja2 import Template
t = Template("Hello {{ 42.baz }}!")
print t.render({42:{'baz':'World'}})
```

It displays `Hello  !` and not `Hello World!`

Is it possible with [jinja2](/questions/tagged/jinja2) to access a numeric key as is it possible to declare a `dict` with numeric keys?

Notice that `{'42':{'baz':'World'}}` is not a solution

Comment: I don't get it, `x` will be undefined in this case and the idea is not to define a `x`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Numbers and strings are evaluated as [literals](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/templates/#literals), and you cannot force Jinja to treat them as variable names because of how the Jinja's [name patterns](https://github.com/mitsuhiko/jinja2/blob/master/jinja2/lexer.py#L42) work. So `{{ 42 }}` means `42` and not variable named `42`.

The simplest solution would be to do like that:

```
from jinja2 import Template
t = Template("Hello {{ vars[42].baz }}!")
print t.render(vars={42:{'baz':'World'}})
```

The `vars` is just a name, it can be whatever you want.